# Deadline of Completing DS-160 Form

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I have an appointment with US consular on May 15. I just finished my D-160 form today (at May 10). The system does not give any error and confirmed my application. Hence, I wonder that is there any problem because of the completion time of DS-160 form. Because there is not too much time between May 10 and May 15.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details? Why do you think there might be a problem?

Comment: In some forums I read that we need to finish d-160 application form before 3 weekday from apoointment day. If this statement is true maybe I can face with some problem because today is friday, and my appoinment is wednesday morning. There are only two weekday between today and my appointment day (monday and tuesday) @JJJ

Comment: Alright, in that case I'd recommend adding that into your question, perhaps with a link to one of those statements.

Comment: The links that I read is not in english so I don't think that is very useful. So do you know anything about the deadline of completing D-160 Form ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about visa applications. Many people here do, so I upvoted the relevant comment too and hopefully someone can provide a little more insight. ;)

Comment: Thanks for upvoting the question and bringing it to the forefront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no minimum time requirement between submission of application electronically and interview date **particularly for non-immigrant visas**. What you're hearing is all anecdotal stories.

Not only does the [Department of State website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application.html) not mention anything like that, I know people who have applied and gone for interviews within a couple of days. Hypothetically you can submit an application today and if you get an appointment for today you can appear for your interview.

**TL:DR**

With immigrant visa applications it is slightly different, after your petition has been approved by USCIS, you need to hear from the consulate that you can apply for a visa before proceeding.

Back in the day 90's when applications were purely paper based, the same date you submit your application you are interviewed, admittedly that is very long ago.

Comment: There is no waiting time. If an appointment is available you can go immediately, just remember to bring your barcode printout.